# SendGrid has no marketing option in the side panel

Tags: azure, sendgrid

I signed up for a free SendGrid account via the Azure portal. I want to use Marketing lists for emails however there is no option for "Marketing" in the side panel. Every tutorial I watch has this "Marketing" option available.

What I see

[image]

What I see on every youtube tutorial

[image]

Does anyone know how to get the marketing options?

Answer (score 2):

Great question. SendGrid partners with Microsoft Azure and other companies to offer a more seamless onboarding and billing experience.
However, some products like the marketing suite are not yet available at this moment when consuming SendGrid services through our partners.

If you need the marketing suite, you can [create an account directly through SendGrid](https://signup.sendgrid.com/) instead of through Azure.

I understand this may be inconvenient, so I'm passing your query along as feedback for the SendGrid team.