# In Sendgrid, is there a way to identify what Azure account or directory the account is attached to?

Tags: azure, sendgrid

In Sendgrid, is there a way to identify what Azure account or directory the account is attached to? Our company has over a dozen Azure directories but we have a single SendGrid account for many of our applications. We've identified that we have our account set up via Azure from [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72357650/sendgrid-has-no-marketing-option-in-the-side-panel), but we need more info. The one who created the Sendgrid setup has left the company and we are trying to re-establish where everything is.

**Where I've Looked**

I see that there is a "Manage your plan in Azure" button when I look at Account Details (see screenshot below), but when I click on it, it merely redirects me to the Cost Management page of the Azure directory I am currently logged into. It works the same if I log out of Microsoft first before clicking the button.

Perhaps more promising but still unhelpful is under the "Account" tab under Account Details, which shows an Admin Account which reads something like "azure_acct_123456789012345678901234567890
firstlast@ourcompanydomain.com" where the [firstlast] is the name of the old admin who left. The number indicated is too long be a Directory ID.

[image]